# Replace only after specific pattern

Tags: regular-expression

I have lines like this:

```
$params["request_id_$i"] => $v["request_id_$i"];
$params["drug_name_$i"] => $v["drug_name"];
```

I want to replace all _ occuring after "=>" with "-". I am able to replace
single "_" with following:

```
s/^.*=> \zs\(.\{-}\)_\(.\{-}\)$/\1-\2/g
```

But how to do it for multiple _ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a lookbehind assertion

```
s/\(=>.*\)\@<=_/-/g
```

This is telling vim to check backwards for `=>` for each possible `_` match.

Answer (score 2):

It's not elegant, but it works:

```
:%s/=> \zs\(.*\)/\=substitute(submatch(1), '_', '-', 'g')/
```

I'm sure someone more talented with regexp than I am can find a way that doesn't require the use of a submatch and a second substitute.